# get polygon from Qvariant

Tags: qt

i have define a qvariant with metatype of QMetaType::QPolygon but im not able to retrieve the QPolygon from the QVariant.

QVariant is having toInt(), toLin(), toList() but not toPolygon(). but not any function call to convert it back to QPolygon .

Comment: Such a coincidence! Someone has just asked a similar question (but more general): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24362946/how-can-i-cast-a-qvariant-to-custom-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the template method `T QVariant::value()` for that.

Example:

```
QPolygon poly = myVariant.value<QPolygon>();
```