# How to convert QVariant to QDomNode

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

I have a simple DOM model for working with XML (from this tutorial: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpledommodel-example.html). Now in my code I want to get data by index like this:

```
auto data = model_->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole);
```

But method `data()` returns `QVariant` and I want to convert it to `QDomNode`. How can I do that? I have tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24363059/5955876, but it didn't help. I guess it is because `QDomNode` isn't `QObject`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `data()` function of our model. What you need is just extracting `QDomNode` object from the model index. I.e.:

```
[..]
QModelIndex index =  model_->index(row, column);
DomItem *item = static_cast<DomItem *>(index.internalPointer());
QDomNode node = item->node();
```